# How to transform database weekday name to system weekday name

Tags: r

I have a database with dates and the corresponding day of the week. However, I would like to know if it is possible to change the days of the week names of this database for the the system's weekdays names, that is, instead of being `wednesday day` it would be `Wednesday`, which is the form that is in the system. I believe I would have to use the `wkday` function somehow

```
df1 <- structure(
  list(date = c("2021-06-23","2021-06-24","2021-06-30","2021-07-01"),
       Week= c("wednesday day","thursday day","wednesday day","thursday day")),
  class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would look something like this. The `weekdays()` function is used to give a date and get the day of the week back.

```
df1$Week <- weekdays(df1$date)
```

Working reproduction:

```
df1 <- structure(
    list(date = c("2021-06-23","2021-06-24","2021-06-30","2021-07-01"),
         Week= c("wednesday day","thursday day","wednesday day","thursday day")),
         class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))

df1$date <- as.Date(df1$date)

df1$Week <- weekdays(df1$date)

df1
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, but when I run your code, it appears: `Error in UseMethod("weekdays") : 
  no applicable method for 'weekdays' applied to an object of class "character`

Comment: @Antonio that means `df1$date` is in character format and not date format

Comment: ah ok, thanks for reply!

Comment: @Antonio you're very welcome